# Checking the class of a Java Reflection Type

Tags: java, reflection

I've been going through the answers I've seen on SO and thus far I can't find any solutions that work correctly for me. Essentially I'm just using reflection to get a method, and then get all its parameter types like this:

```
Type[] parameters = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
```

From there I am iterating through the `parameters` to get their respective classes so I can pass the correct data. I've tried the following:

```
Type currentType = parameters[index];
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(currentType.getClass().getName());
if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(Number.class)) {
     //do stuff that is number specific
     //EG drill down farther into specific subclass like int,
     //double, etc for more exact parsing
} else if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
     //Do stuff that is specific to string
} else {
     //Nope, no love here.
}
```

But it doesn't correctly detect when it should be a `Number` or `String` and always falls into the last else statement. There must be something really simple that I'm overlooking, but for the life of me I cannot determine what it could be.

Thanks to all in advance.

Update: Here is a really simple example of a method stub I'm parsing. It isn't anything complicated.

```
public void methodWithInt(int integer){
    //do something
}

public void methodWithString(String string){
    //do something else
}
```

Update: Based on `Sotirios Delimanolis` answer I've made some progress.

```
if (currentType instanceof Class) {
    Class<?> currentClazz = (Class<?>) currentType;
    if (currentClazz.isAssignableFrom(Number.class)) {
        // This isn't getting reached for either int or Integer
    } else if (currentClazz.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
        // This IS working correctly for strings
    } else {
        // Both int and Integer fall here
    }
} else {
    // Are primitives supposed to be handled here? If so int isn't
    // being sent here, but is falling in the the else from the
    // condition previous to this one.
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example method signature?

Comment: question 1: why are you using reflection? I ask, because it's usually a sign that you're using the wrong approach to solve the problem you're really having. Unless your doing some kind of blind loading, you generally want to stay as far away from reflection for as long as possible (it's a great tool that exists to make use of when you have no other choice).

Comment: What does `currentType.getClass().getName()` return? I think it isn't what you expect. I suggest you google the javadocs for this method.

Comment: Also, `int.class` and `Integer.class` are two different things.

Comment: I second @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Why are you using reflection? What is the original problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I understand this may potentially not be the best way to do this, but we're working on integrating some testing functionality to testing suites that already exist but lack what we need. Unfortunately the choice is not mine and was made by people with higher standing at our company.

Comment: @BCqrstoO that's a legitimate reason (just be aware that the moment someone add a SecurityManager to the code, reflection becomes impossible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Type currentType = parameters[index];
```

already gives you the type of the parameter.

Calling

```
currentType.getClass()
```

returns a `Class` object for the type `Type`, not what you want.

[`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a [`Type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) subtype. You can check if the `Type` reference you have is an `instanceof` of `Class` and then perform your `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to go about this. `if (currentType instanceof Number){` Doesn't recognize `int` or `Integer`. Additionally `else if (currentType instanceof String) {` Won't even compile as it give me a compiler error. Can you elaborate or point me in the direction of some documentation to help me better understand?

Comment: @BCqrstoO No, the `Type` object is potentially a `Class`, so `if (currentType instanceof Class)`. Then cast `currentType` to a `Class` reference so that you can use it in `isAssignableFrom`.

Comment: I think I have it now, or at least almost. I have updated the question to reflect what I believe you are trying to convey to me. It is correctly handling String object, but doesn't seem to be catching primitive `int` or boxed `Integers` in either case. Sorry for all the pestering, but reflection is very new to me.

Comment: @BCqrstoO For one, your `isAssignableFrom` is backwards. The method should be invoked on the super type. So `String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)` (even though `String` cannot have subtypes) and `Number.class.isAssignableFrom(..)`. Additionally, and I tried to hint at this in the comments, your parameter of type `int` would have a `int.class` type object. `int.class` is not the same as `Integer.class` and definitely is not assignable to `Number.class`.

Comment: Sorry I did actually figure out they were backwards, but I haven't updated the question to reflect that. I'll continue on my own and figure out how to handle the primitives. Thanks for your help!